# Error: Failed to lookup view "/listings" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, package.json

I am getting the error `Error: Failed to lookup view "/listings"` in views directory, I have tried moved the `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` below the app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); and vice versa no luck.  Also in the app.get I did `('/listings/index)` still got nothing.

my file structure

```
node_modules
views\listings
   listings.ejs
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));




let listings = [{
        listingAgent: 'Todd Barkley',
        Review: 'Awesome Agent'
    },
    {
        listingAgent: 'David Smith',
        Review: 'Good agent'
    },
    {
        listingAgent: 'Erick Jones',
        Review: 'Terrible agent, glad we fired him'
    }
]


app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/listings', { listings });
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("On port 4000")
})
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Public Listings</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Public Listings</h1>
    <ul>
        <% for (let l of listings ) {%>
            <li>
                <%= l.Review %>
                    <b><%=l.listingAgent  %> </b>
            </li>
            <% } %>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "practicerest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Practice ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Manny Verma",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the description of your directory structure in the question?

Comment: I added my file structure in the question.

Comment: So the HTML content is in the file `index.ejs` or `listings.ejs` ?

Comment: its in the listings.ejs

Comment: is my requires good or do they need to be re ordered?  Does it matter how they are put in?

Comment: Can you try my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure, `views` folder has the correct name. Secondly, check the files extension are correct and lastly the path in the render:

```
app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    res.render('listings', { listings }); // remove the slash to get the correct path
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the file `listings.ejs`  is in the `views\listings` folder, the code should be :

```
app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    res.render('listings/listings', { listings });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your ejs file name is `index`, but you are trying to render `listings` file which does not exist.

secondly, you don't need to use `/` before your file name.

## solution

so basically all you have to do is either change your ejs file name to `listings` or change the render arg to `index`.

and finally, remove `/` before the file name.

```js
//index.ejs
app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { listings });
})
```

```js
//listings.ejs
app.get('/listings', (req, res) => {
    res.render('listings', { listings });
})
```

Comment: I get the same error, I tried both the index.ejs and listings.ejs I still get the failed to lookup view "listings"

Comment: fortunately, it seems you have solved the issue by now. but if my solution didn't fix the issue, it's probably because of the file structure.